# Batch resize a folder full of SVG

Tags: 18.04, resize, inkscape, batch, svg

I have some `Google Material Design icons` in a folder. Around 100 of them in a folder. They are very small, the canvas is only 24x24 px. I got `Inkscape` installed and can resize them one by one. But there is a total of 1000 + SVGs and resizing them one by one will take ages.

It would be great if someone can help me batch resize the content of each folder ( around 10 folders altogether). I am trying to resize to 48px or 64 px size. Thanks.

PS : I am using 18.04.

Comment: Pixel sizes does not make much sense with SVG's. They're vector drawings.

Comment: Thank you. I am planning to make a symbol set out of it. A bit worried about using small sized canvas. Hence the question.